# Как импортировать из соседней директории

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Структура проекта (условного):

```
example/
└── src/
    ├── a/
    │   └── here.py
    └── b/
        └── importing.py
```

<sub>`src/b/importing.py`</sub>

```py
def sqr(x): return x * x
```

Способов импорта `sqr` из `src/b/importing.py` в `src/b/here.py` много, но все они приводят в ошибкам.

```py
from example.b.importing import sqr
```

Ошибка: `No module named 'example'`.

```py
from ..b.importing import sqr
```

Ошибка: `attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

```py
from b.importing import sqr
```

Ошибка: `No module named 'b'`.

Добавлял `__init__.py` во все возможные папки, удалял — ничего не менялось. Добавлял `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='example', version='1.0.0', package_dir='src')
```

Также безуспешно.

Как сделать этот импорт?

Comment: граждане, за что минусы? если в питоне нет javascript'овских импортов, так и скажите. если вы минусуете, вы хотите, чтобы я удалил вопрос, но за что его удалять? пока складывается ощущение, что те 2 человека, которые давали мне ответы на вопросы поставили эти минусы :)

Comment: Не вижу второго)

Comment: @YanWolf он удалили ответ, они видны, вроде как, с 10к репы, так что я тоже того ответа не вижу)

Answer (score 1):

И так, структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**src\a\ **init**.py**

```
from src.a.main_a import foo_a

# импорт делает функцию foo_a() доступной напрямую из src.a.main_a
```

**src\b\ **init**.py**

```
from src.b.main_b import foo_b
```

**src\a\main_a.py**

```
def foo_a():
    print('С тобой говорит MAIN_A')
```

**src\a\main_b.py**

```
def foo_b():
    print('С тобой говорит MAIN_B')
```

**main.py**

```
from src.a import foo_a 
from src.b import foo_b

foo_a()
foo_b()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы импортировать функцию из main_b.py в main_a.py:

**main_a.py**

```
from src.b import foo_Bb

foo_Bb()
```

**src\b\ init.py**

```
from src.b.main_b import foo_b

def foo_Bb():
    foo_b()
```

Немного науки:

Абсолютный и относительный импорт
При абсолютном импорте используется полный путь (от начала корневой папки проекта) к желаемому модулю.

При относительном импорте используется относительный путь (начиная с пути текущего модуля) к желаемому модулю. Есть два типа относительных импортов:

При явном импорте используется формат from .<модуль/пакет> import X, где символы точки . показывают, на сколько директорий «вверх» нужно подняться. Одна точка . показывает текущую директорию, две точки .. — на одну директорию выше и т. д.
Неявный относительный импорт пишется так, как если бы текущая директория была частью sys.path. Такой тип импортов поддерживается только в Python 2.
В документации Python об относительных импортах в Python 3 написано следующее:

Единственный приемлемый синтаксис для относительных импортов — from .[модуль] import [имя]. Все импорты, которые начинаются не с точки ., считаются абсолютными.

Источник: What’s New in Python 3.0

В качестве примера допустим, что мы запускаем start.py, который импортирует a1, который импортирует other, a2 и sa1. Тогда импорты в a1.py будут выглядеть следующим образом:

Абсолютные импорты:

import other

import packA.a2

import packA.subA.sa1

Явные относительные импорты:

import other

from . import a2

from .subA import sa1

Неявные относительные импорты (не поддерживаются в Python 3):

import other

import a2

import subA.sa1

Учтите, что в относительных импортах с помощью точек . можно дойти только до директории, содержащей запущенный из командной строки скрипт (не включительно). Таким образом, from .. import other не сработает в a1.py. В результате мы получим ошибку ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.

Как правило, абсолютные импорты предпочтительнее относительных. Они позволяют избежать путаницы между явными и неявными импортами. Кроме того, любой скрипт с явными относительными импортами нельзя запустить напрямую:

Имейте в виду, что относительные импорты основаны на имени текущего модуля. Так как имя главного модуля всегда "**main**", модули, которые должны использоваться как главный модуль приложения, должны всегда использовать абсолютные импорты.

Источник: Python 2 и Python 3

Comment: вы читали вопрос? мне в файле `main_a.py` нужно сделать импорт `main_b.py`, из корневой директории я и сам импорт сделать могу

Comment: Смотрите правки в ответе

Comment: Теперь это  то, что вы хотели?

Comment: та нет же, мне не нужно указывать `src`. я хочу именно без `src`, чтобы путь был относителен

Comment: я смотрел numpy, там они как-то указывают имя пакета, и линтер не ругается, я понятия не имею, как они так сделали

Comment: Python 3 не поддерживает такие импорты. Внимательнее прочитайте документацию.

Comment: No named module 'src'  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Этот ответ не отвечает на вопрос, поэтому считаю, что нет смысла этого ответа.