# Как импортировать модуль лежащий выше на два каталога?

Tags: python, файловые-пути, pathlib

Имею следующую структура проекта:

[image: Имею следующую структура проекта:]

В файле env.py пытаюсь импортировать:

```
from backend.config import DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_USER
from backend.sql.models import metadata
```

Но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
  from backend.config import DB_USER, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_HOST
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как импортировать из соседней директории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343188/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: `from ..config import ...`?

Comment: @wchistow ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'E:\VTB\backend')
import conf

conf.foo()
```